# What is the rationale behind disabling Superfetch on SSD systems?

Tags: windows-7, ssd, superfetch

I understand that Superfetch was designed to use RAM for caching with HDDs in mind due to their high latencies, something that SSDs don't have. However, I don't understand how an SSD could outperform RAM.

Does Windows 7 automatically disable Superfetch on systems with fast enough SSDs solely to free up more RAM?

Comment: As an aside for those new to using an SSD with Windows, it is also highly recommended that you disable Disk Defragmenter for the same reasons cited below.  A new installation of Windows 7 on an SSD should have Defrag disabled when you install, but upgrading from a standard disk to an SSD will require that it be disabled manually as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why SSD manufacturers recommend turning off SuperFetch is because SSD's can only take so many read/write cycles to the same sector before performance degrades and SuperFetch will read and write to the same sector repeatedly.

Comment: More specifically, Superfetch won't run on drive with high random-access speed http://blogs.msdn.com/b/e7/archive/2009/05/05/support-and-q-a-for-solid-state-drives-and.aspx It will still run on other drives (if any)

Comment: Over a decade later, to my knowledge, SSDs have advanced so that the same sector will no longer be read to / written from repeatedly.

Answer (score 5):

It is not so much that the SSD that will be faster than the RAM, but that the lifespan of the SSD will be decreased. The benefits don't outweigh the cost.